# Hook pre/post in pledge changed status

Tags: hooks, pledges, civipledge, status

On 5.6.0

- After create a pledge.
- If is created a new contribution that change the status of the pledge from "Pending" to "Completed" is not incoming in any hook_civicrm_post or hook_civicrm_pre with objectName equal to "Pledge" or "PledgePayment"

Which is the correct way to update the pledge programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

I see this line in `CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution`:

```
//update pledge and pledge payment, CRM-3961
CRM_Pledge_BAO_PledgePayment::resetPledgePayment($id);
```

Looking at `CRM_Pledge_BAO_PledgePayment::resetPledgePayment()`, I see it calls the DAO method, not the BAO - which is why the hooks (which ARE present) are bypassed.

I think this would be a good enhancement for core CiviCRM.  `CRM_Pledge_BAO_PledgePayment::resetPledgePayment()` is a very short function, which could be easily refactored to instantiate the PledgePayment BAO instead of DAO, and call the `add()` or `create()` method instead of `commit()`.  This would cause your hooks to fire.